# Java - Saving to txt file duplicates first entry

Tags: java, duplicates, filewriter, printwriter

I have been working on a small library application which allows manuals to be stored. So far I have implemented code to allow my application to save to an existing text file, I would like the same file to be updated each time the user saves, and not overwritten.

Currently if I enter 1 manual and save the library, the text file is updated. But if I add a second manual to the library then save, the first manual is duplicated in the text file

Here is an example of the text file after a second manual is added:

[image]

Here is the code I am using to save:

```
//Choice 7: Save Library:

if(Menu.menuChoice == 7 && Library.ManualList.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println(Messages.addManualFirst);
    Menu.displayMenu();
}

else if(Menu.menuChoice == 7){
    Library.displayManualList();
    boolean saveYesNo = Console.readYesNo("\nThe ManualKeeper® app is able to save your current library to a '.txt' \nfile in your workspace directory.\n\nWould you like to save the current library? (Y/N):\n");
    if(saveYesNo){
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Library.txt", true);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

            for (int i = 0; i < Library.ManualList.size(); i++){
                pw.println("-------------------- Index Number: " + i + " --------------------");
                pw.println(Library.ManualList.get(i).displayManual());
                pw.println("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
            }
            pw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error! Library unable to save.");
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("\n                              Library saved!\n");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
    else if(saveYesNo){
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    Menu.displayMenu();

}
```

If anyone knows how I might be able to get the first manual to stop duplicating, please let me know :)

Comment: Could you also provide us the code of displayManual() method ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused, you're saying you don't want to overwrite the file, you want to append to it... And that's exactly what's happening.

The PrintWriter will append to the existing file. So I'm assuming what happens is that on your first run, it creates the initial 'index 0' block. On your subsequent run it just appends to the file, duplicating the first entry.

To avoid this you could just create your file object from scratch every time, eg:

```
File file = new File("Library.txt");
file.delete();
file.createNewFile();
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
```

But as your question is described, it seems like the problem you're encountering is exactly what you want..?

Comment: This stops the duplication however I would like the same "Library.txt" file to be added to the next time the application is launched. Is there any way I can do this? Right now if I add manuals to the librar, save and close the app everything is fine. But if the user launches the app again the Library text file empties itself! How can I get this information to be retained in the text file without duplication?

Comment: Well first of all, if you want to retain the contents of the Library.txt file when the program is launched, you'll need to load the contents of the file when the program initializes. Basically you'd need to `deserialize` your file contents back into Manual objects. And then add them to your `Library.ManualList`. Then when the you write your list back to the file, it will contain the file's previous contents, and whatever else was added during that run of the program.